# Erro ao executar comando react-native init

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, osx, mac

Estou tentando criar um projeto `React Native` no `MacOs` pelo `Terminal`.
Digito os seguintes comandos no Terminal:

```
> cd Desktop

> mkdir curso-react

> cd curso-react/

> react-native init exercicios
```

Após executar o comando `react-native init exercicios` o seguinte erro de permissão é exibido para mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver ?

Comment: tentou com sudo para ver se funciona? `sudo react-native init exercicios`

Comment: Deu certo usando o comando o sudo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro de permissão na pasta foi corrigido com o comando `sudo` antes do comando `react-native`, ficando da seguinte maneira o comando completo:

```
> sudo react-native init exercicios
```